# Postgresql JSon rows to key-value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

currently I have following postgresql json object in form of arrays object

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "dollar",
    "sign": "$",
    "exchange_rate": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Riel",
    "sign": "៛",
    "exchange_rate": 4085
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Baht",
    "sign": "b",
    "exchange_rate": 30.55
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Dong",
    "sign": "d",
    "exchange_rate": 16000
  }
]
```

and the arrays object is the result of the following query:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(record))
from (
select
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.sign,
    c.exchange_rate
from  currency c) record;
```

but the result above is slightly different to my needs. I want to switch that arrays to another form of key, value object just as below, so I can traversal the json through id value.

```
{
      "1": {
        "name": "dollar",
        "sign": "$",
        "exchange_rate": 1
      },
      "2": {
        "name": "Riel",
        "sign": "៛",
        "exchange_rate": 4085
      },
      "3": {
        "name": "Baht",
        "sign": "b",
        "exchange_rate": 30.55
      },
      "4": {
        "name": "Dong",
        "sign": "d",
        "exchange_rate": 16000
      }
    }
```

Anyone provide me some help for this problem pls. Respect all your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_BUILD_OBJECT()` along with `JSON_OBJECT_AGG()` might be used

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(id,
                       JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('name',name,
                                         'sign',sign,
                                         'exchange_rate',exchange_rate))
  FROM currency
```

**or** *keeping the original function* consider briefly using

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(id, ROW_TO_JSON(c)::JSONB - 'id' )
  FROM currency AS c
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a00cbac93027b82523e9951a6c1d0fb9)</kbd>

**P.S:** `JSONB_PRETTY()` might be added, *as stated in the demo, wrapping up the applied outermost function*, in order to display the result formatted well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can make it  now.